# wrong comparison result (logical error ) for numbers with 3 digits vb.net program

Tags: vb.net, comparison

Good morning, I am learning vb.net and created a simple from related to employee data
I have a search button that always displays the correct result except when searching for a salary with a condition (e.g when the selected searching option for salary  is less than, greater, or between) from the radioButton.

For example: When I search for salaries below 2, it retrieves all employee data while there is no employee who has salary below 1000

I am using Access database and when I call the salary from the database and the value entered in (txtSearch) the correct values are appear!
I don't know why I have wrong results when comparing some salaries condition. As if it's sometimes doing a comparison just for the digits regardless the whole number of each number or something e.g (2 > 12 is true!)

Here is some screenshots -------- >

first img should not return any employee since no one have salary less than 200

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caPd6.png)

, the 2nd one return a correct value

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkFc1.png)

, ok 2 and 3 are correct results but like it just compared digit by digit, see the next image

[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzUc5.png)

"wrong result!, all the salaries are grater than 140 but it only return 3 employee data"

[img4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwnKp.png)

!!

[img5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpkAn.png)

thanks in advance and sorry for my English

```
  Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
   
    Dim strSearch As String = "select * from employeeData where "
      If radioSalary.Checked Then
        strSearch &= " [Salary] = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
    ElseIf radioSalLess.Checked Then
        strSearch &= " [Salary] < '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
    ElseIf radioSalGreator.Checked Then
        strSearch &= " [Salary] > '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
    ElseIf radioSalBetween.Checked Then
        strSearch &= " [Salary] between '" & txtSearch.Text & "' and '" & txtSearch2.Text & "'"
    End If
dgvEmps.DataSource = getTable(strSearch)
End Sub
```

Comment: edit: I figure that the wrong is from the query, but  how can I fix it

Comment: Make sure the data type of the `Salary` field in the DB is the correct type and use [OleDbParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

Comment: My problem is that I am trying to compare two salaries(numbers) but they are all as strings datatype so they compare with the index.
I want to compare the numbers as number value and when I try to modify the salary data type in the database to be a number, I got a lot of errors with my project
Is there any way to keep on the database without any change on it and just change the salary datatype when comparing? for example parsing or casting or something like that, and if yes please tell me how to do it

Comment: No, that will be a bad design. In your DB, when you create a new table and add new fields, you should select the right [Data Type](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_data_types.htm) for each. You can't compare strings the same way you do for currencies and other numeric types. So, a good backend design will make your frontend implementation so easy. Please read [this](https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/visual-basic-net/7258/adding-and-saving-records-access-database-using-vbnet.html) and similar posts. Also [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRVBpTFa3To) tutorials.

Comment: You are right, thanks

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com has some good learning opportunities for you too